# How does Google tracking Cookie work?

Tags: cookies

I had an incomplete order on one of my favorite websites.  I left the website and browsed to a coding resource website.  There I noticed an advertisement for the website I was on which I had not completed an order(the aforementioned site).  After doing some google, I came across some people saying that they had similar issues and cause was Google's tracking Cookie.  How could this work?  How can Google know which sites I am at through a cookie?

Also, I am curious where this information(The cookie) info is stored so that I can look at it?

Comment: have you read the Google Analytics documentation?

Comment: @Brian No, I thought Google Analytics is Analytics for your personal webstie?

Comment: Google Analytics uses the Google tracking cookie. So, if the site you were visiting uses GA, and you visit another site that displays Google Ads, and Site A has purchased impressions from Google Ads, then bingo... you have yourself an ad from the site you just visited. Honestly, you're right, GA probably has nothing to do with it, but that's how I learned about the Google tracking cookie.

Comment: I thought that some privacy statement of google promises not to use GA data in such a way.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I believe there is an opt out clause

Answer (score 0):

While not Google-specific, here is a nice & simple overview of tracking cookies:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCduHebLzCA

This page of Google Analytics FAQ lists which cookies are created when you visit a page with Google Analytics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsCookies#cookiesSet